# Code doesn't write all data to csv file after adding looping mechanisms

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading in data from a netCDF file and reducing it to a vector and then writing the vector to a csv file. The data reformatting works fine but when I try to write the data to a csv it doesn't write the whole file. In fact it doesn't even write a csv file it writes a generic "file" type.

```py
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import os
import csv

'''
I'm importing the lists I need to automate file extraction from a seperate file
to reduce clutter
'''
from gmLists import files #Stores the different paths I need
from gmLists import variableNames #Stores names of variables
from gmLists import years #Years I have data for
from gmLists import urlPrefix #Used to get files
from gmLists import yearlyDataList #Used to store numpy arrays
#Used to store the names of the csv files to be created
from gmLists import csvFileNames 


for i in range(10):
    os.chdir(files[0]) #Read from here

    for j in range(16):
        #Name of specific file in directory
        url = urlPrefix[0] + str(years[j]) + ".nc" 
        temp = netCDF4.Dataset(url).variables[variableNames[i]][:,::] 


        dataYear = temp[:,179:408,10:235] 

        # do monthly mean here
        if(years[j]%4 != 0):
            January = np.mean(dataYear[0:31,::], axis=0)      
            February = np.mean(dataYear[31:59,::], axis=0)     
            March = np.mean(dataYear[59:90,::], axis=0)     
            April = np.mean(dataYear[90:120,::], axis=0)
            May = np.mean(dataYear[120:151,::], axis=0)
            June = np.mean(dataYear[151:181,::], axis=0)
            July = np.mean(dataYear[181:212,::], axis=0)
            August = np.mean(dataYear[212:243,::], axis=0)
            September = np.mean(dataYear[243:273,::], axis=0)
            October = np.mean(dataYear[273:304,::], axis=0)
            November = np.mean(dataYear[304:334,::], axis=0)
            December = np.mean(dataYear[334:365,::], axis=0)
        else:
           # for leap year
           January = np.mean(dataYear[0:31,::], axis=0)     
           February = np.mean(dataYear[31:60,::], axis=0)     
           March = np.mean(dataYear[60:91,::], axis=0)     
           April = np.mean(dataYear[91:121,::], axis=0)
           May = np.mean(dataYear[121:152,::], axis=0)
           June = np.mean(dataYear[152:182,::], axis=0)
           July = np.mean(dataYear[182:213,::], axis=0)
           August = np.mean(dataYear[213:244,::], axis=0)
           September = np.mean(dataYear[244:274,::], axis=0)
           October = np.mean(dataYear[274:305,::], axis=0)
           November = np.mean(dataYear[305:335,::], axis=0)
           December = np.mean(dataYear[335:366,::], axis=0)

    monthlyData = np.stack([January, February, March, April, May, June, July, 
                            August, September, October, November, December], 
                            axis=0)

    yearlyDataList.append(monthlyData)


totalMonthlyData = np.vstack([yearlyDataList[0], yearlyDataList[1], 
yearlyDataList[2], yearlyDataList[3], yearlyDataList[4], yearlyDataList[5],
yearlyDataList[6], yearlyDataList[7], yearlyDataList[8], yearlyDataList[9],
yearlyDataList[10], yearlyDataList[11], yearlyDataList[12], 
yearlyDataList[13], yearlyDataList[14], yearlyDataList[15]]) 

# flatten the array to vector
flattenedMonthlyData = np.reshape(totalMonthlyData, (np.product(totalMonthlyData.shape),))

#The below code is where I think the problem is
os.chdir('saveDirectory') # your save destination

csvfile = csvFileNames[0]

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in flattenedMonthlyData:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

I hope I didn't include too much code. I know for a fact that the code that reads in the netCDF files and reformatts it is correct. I included that code in case there's some interaction fouling things up that I didn't see.

Before I added in my looping mechanisms I was successfully able to produce a csv file but since then when I run the code the files made are 5000 kilobytes smaller than my one good csv file and they aren't even csv files. They're some generic file type. Even when I try to go backwards and remove the looping I can't recreate my earlier success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By “writes a generic file type” what do you mean? My suspicion is that ‘csvFilenames[0]’ doesn’t have the “.csv” suffix necessary for the OS to recognize it as such.

Comment: @Bryce Kille I’m such an idiot. Thank you so much.

Comment: We’ve all been there (: does this solve your other problem as well?

Comment: The code takes 30 minutes to read all of the files. They’re pretty big. I won’t know for sure for a while.

Comment: Hmm. A helpful tip from personal experience is to try and reduce the input size for debugging. Either use less files and/or truncate them to a smaller size, just to make sure the logic works.